# How can I update a custom addres field from quote addres to sales order address when creating a multishipping order

Tags: magento2, custom-field, multishipping

I have inserted custom address fields in quote address trough fielset.xml successfully  but it is not working for sales order address, it is not filling custom fields on database. This is when using multishipping process

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">    
        <fieldset id="customer_address">
            
            <field name="descripcion_sucursal">
                <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
            </field>
           
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">
            <field name="descripcion_sucursal">
                <aspect name="to_order_address" />
            </field>
            
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to add the fields to the fieldset.xml

You also have to copy the fieldset using:

\Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy:copyFieldsetToTarget

The most likely place to do this is from an observer. Refer to https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/copy-fieldsets.html step 3. Copying fieldset.

Here are the code you will need to copy a field from quote_address to sales_order_address, I named the field stackexchange. The event I hooked into is: sales_model_service_quote_submit_before.

app/code/StackExchange/QuoteAddress/Observer/CopyStackExchangeToOrderAddress.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchange\QuoteAddress\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy as ObjectCopyService;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CopyStackExchangeToOrderAddress  implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectCopyService
     */
    private ObjectCopyService $objectCopyService;

    public function __construct(
        ObjectCopyService $objectCopyService
    ) {
        $this->objectCopyService = $objectCopyService;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
        /* @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote');

        $this->objectCopyService->copyFieldsetToTarget(
            'sales_convert_quote_address',
            'to_order_address',
            $quote->getShippingAddress(),
            $order->getShippingAddress()
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

app/code/StackExchange/QuoteAddress/etc/fieldset.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">
            <field name="stackexchange">
                <aspect name="to_order_address" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

app/code/StackExchange/QuoteAddress/etc/db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="quote_address">
        <column xsi:type="text"
                name="stackexchange"
                nullable="true"
                comment="stackexchange"
        />
    </table>
    <table name="sales_order_address">
        <column xsi:type="text"
                name="stackexchange"
                nullable="true"
                comment="stackexchange"
        />
    </table>
</schema>
```

app/code/StackExchange/QuoteAddress/etc/events.xml

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
            <observer name="quote_address_copy_field" instance="StackExchange\QuoteAddress\Observer\CopyStackExchangeToOrderAddress"/>
        </event>
    </config>
```

app/code/StackExchange/QuoteAddress/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackExchange_QuoteAddress" setup_version="0.1.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/StackExchange/QuoteAddress/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackExchange_QuoteAddress',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Which event should I use for copying the custom fields from quote address to sales order address?

Comment: I edited the post, the code there works on my local environment

Comment: It is not working for me, have you tested it in a multishipping process?

Answer (score 0):

The above is working fine for Shipping Address. But it is not saving the values for Billing Address. I am using the following code in file - app/code/StackExchange/QuoteAddress/Observer/CopyStackExchangeToOrderAddress.php

```
$this->objectCopyService->copyFieldsetToTarget(
            'sales_convert_quote_address',
            'to_order_address',
            $quote->getBillingAddress(),
            $order->getBillingAddress()
        );
```